# How to turn off, or have a blank base map, in an AGOL Web App?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-online-webmap

I have created a Web App in ArcGIS Online for a team.

I have the Basemap Gallery widget enabled in the header bar, and I am using the organisation defaults.

I'd also like an option to not have a basemap, or select a basemap that is totally blank, so that maps can be presented, or printed, without the 'clutter' of basemap showing through.

I have looked through GIS Stackexchange and through the 'Learn more about this widget' in the Web App builder but I haven't been able to find an answer of whether there is a ready made blank basemap, or discover if there is a workaround that I can do to make this possible, or make one myself?

Comment: Custom basemaps are not supported in the Basemap Gallery Widget for WAB in ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Ok, thanks. At least I can stop looking. I can perhaps make a blank raster layer to do the same job.

Comment: @yogi Do you want to post comment as an answer and I can mark this question answered? Thanks

Comment: that really a good gesture, but posting an answer needs some more formating :), and definitely you can host an empty raster for the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom basemaps are not supported in the Basemap Gallery in Web Apps on ArcGIS Online.

However, a workaround would be to create a blank raster layer that can be included in the layer list to provide a blank background.

*Credit goes to @Yogi*

Answer (score 1):

And other solution, that I mostly use, is to set the basemap transparency to 100%.